# If cell equals condition, find next value in a column and return it's adjacent value

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

I need some help with an excel formula. In E2, I need to do a formula like this:

=if(A2=1,find-in-Column-C-starting-from-C2,where-next-"Fruit"-is, and-return-the-adjacent-cell-in-column-B, else return blank)

[image]

E2 should return B3

E4 should return B5

E6 should return B11

E12 should return B12

E13 should return B17

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following for an array solution that spills the entire result. *I am assuming there is no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*.

```
=LET(A,A1:A16, B,B1:B16, C,C1:C16, seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A)), MAP(A,seq, 
 LAMBDA(x,s,IF(x=1,@FILTER(B,(seq>=s)*(C="Fruit"),""),""))))
```

Here is the output
[image: output]

We use `@`-operator to get the first element of the `FILTER` result. The third `FILTER` input argument is used to prevent any error in case the output is empty.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I am getting an error that this is not a formula. It is strange because I have checked it symbol by symbol and it's the same as yours. See the error here: https://ibb.co/6XRPKXy and here: https://ibb.co/YPymghW. Also, what is strange, Column C is not highlighted when we declare `C,C1:C16`.

Comment: Have you check your excel version?

Comment: I have Office 2019. Which one do I need?

Comment: I got it working with office 365. Thanks for making this elegant solution, David and for point out the importance of the excel version